# JAXB unmarshaller in Message Bean

Tags: jaxb, ejb

I'm using Message Driven Beans. They are pooled, so there are many instances of them. I need to use JAXB unmarshaller in onMessage method. What I want is to create unmarshaller instances in init method, for example:

```
public class MyMDB implemetns MessageListener {
    private Unmarshaller unmarshaller;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        unmarshaller = JAXBContext.newInstance(...)
    }

    public void onMessage(Message message) {
        // use unmarshaller
    }       
}
```

Should I bother about concurrency issues in this scenario? As far as I know unmarshaller isn't thread safe. Should I use ThreadLocal here?

Answer (score 0):

`Unmadshaller` creation is light.  You could hold the reference to the thread safe `JAXBContext` and then create a new `Unmarshaller` each time you need one.